# Как организовать хранение данных?

Tags: android, java, база-данных

Как мне организовать хранение данных? Данные могут дополняться пользователем. Сейчас хочу сохранять в БД, затем оттуда извлекать или просто сохранить свои данные в коде в массиве, а новые данные добавлять в БД. Еще есть описание, описание я хочу хранить в строковых ресурсах, а БД хранить его ключи, для того чтобы кому-то на русском, кому-то на английском.

Comment: А у вас виндовс стоит, Опера или Винрар? И надо ли грабить корованы?

Comment: забыл дописать, что это надо на андроид

Comment: а ну тогда всё понятно (сарказм)

Comment: "кому-то на русском, кому-то на английском" Вы что, пытаетесь локализовать приложение? Это делается совсем не так. В Андроиде есть отличный механизм локализации.

Comment: в БД я буду хранить ключи от ресурсов, и по этому ключу я хочу обращаться к ресурсам.

Comment: @eldqs я это понял, но все же - зачем??!! Это подозрительно напоминает велосипед из костылей...

Comment: @metalurgus В БД храню данные, там имена, значения, описания, 
когда я буду оттуда вытаскивать, не могу же все показывать на английском или только на русском, там храню ключи от строкового ресурса.
Вот таким образом делаю, только подозреваю, что неправильно так, потому и решил спросить здесь, 
а как вы предлагаете или делаете такое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос "как достать строку из ресурсов по ее имени?" находится в гугле за 38 сек. (засекал)  
А вот собственно и ответ.

```
    private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
      String packageName = getPackageName();
      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
      return getString(resId);
    }
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это не единственная проблема, которая у вас возникла? Как только вы **нормально** опишете оставшиеся проблемы, вам сразу же помогут. В том числе и я. Подумайте, и переформулируйте ваши вопросы. Я буду мониторить ваш вопрос периодически.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) и только SQLite - православное средство для хранения данных под Android да и под iOS

Comment: я не спрашивал, какую БД использовать, 
мне интересно, как можно сделать хранение данных в массиве или в БД и как хранить ключи от строкового ресурса, и как его из ресурса вытаскивать

Comment: @eldqs, вы какой-то бред спросили. Никто не понял, что вам надо. А вы еще и возмущаетесь, что вам что-то не то ответили. Научитесь излагать свои мысли.

Comment: да вы правы, но можно и вопросы задать и я не возмущался, просто писал что в голову пришло без каких либо таких намерений

Answer (score 1):

Я что-то тоже не очень понял.
У Вас есть свои данные, которые будут распространяться вместе с программой, и их нужно будет потом изменять?
Тогда однозначно в базе хранить [примерно как-то так](http://www.pandacoder.com/loadingsqlite_db_from_assets/).

Comment: А вот, к примеру, в одном поле хранится ключ от строкового ресурса, 
как мне по этому ключу вытащить значение:
 
    String s = "key";
    getString(R.string.s);

Comment: хм. Ну вообще можно, только Вы не тем путем идете и явно что-то не то пытаетесь сделать.

Можно вот так:
  Class<?> c=R.string.class;
  try {
   Field z=c.getDeclaredField("key");
   int x=z.getInt(c);
   Log.d("zzz",String.valueOf(x));
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) { }